# What is the difference between lsmeans in R and margins in Stata?

Tags: r, stata

Context: I am using Stata to recreate someone else's analysis which was done in R.

In Stata I have used the [margins](https://www3.nd.edu/~rwilliam/stats3/Margins01.pdf) command to calculate the average adjusted predictions for a logistic model. I thought the other analyst used the [lsmeans](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lsmeans/lsmeans.pdf) package to do the same thing however when I run margins in Stata I get a different output than R provides with lsmeans, even though the datasets and coefficients from the regressions are identical.

My understanding was that margins is the Stata equivalent of lsmeans (or can be used as such) but that does not appear to be the case. So I have a two questions:
1. What is the difference between lsmeans and margins (besides language)?
2. How can I replicate R's lsmeans in Stata?

Comment: You might want to provide some example code here for both, ideally on a toy dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to CrossValidated.

I don't know what Stata does, but I do know what `lsmeans()` does: it obtains predictions on a regular grid of factor values, and the marginal lsmeans are obtained by averaging those predictions together *with equal weights*.

So one possibility is that Stata `margins` does not use equal weights. If so, you can check to see if you get the same results as Stata if you change the weights -- e.g., `lsmeans(..., weights = "prop")`; see the documentation for `lsmeans()`.

Another issue, given that this is logistic regression, is what scale those margins are computed on. The **lsmeans** package, by default, computes the marginal averages on  the logit scale (i.e., the linear-predictor scale), and if you specify `type = "response"`, it will back-transpose the marginal averages to the probability scale. But it is possible that `margins` back-transforms first and averages later, which would produce different results.

By the way, there has been no new development or updates of **lsmeans** for about a year, because it has been superseded by the **emmeans** package (which still provides an `lsmeans()` function as an alias for `emmeans()`). I recommend you install **emmeans** and use that in the future. The **emmeans** package has quite a few vignettes that you can access via https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans. The one on basics explains the rudiments of emmeans (aka lsmeans), and the one on transformations discusses how to change when the back-transforming is done relative to the averaging.

I hope this answer helps on the R end. I can't help with getting Stata to do the same thing, though; sorry.